# Advantages/Disadvantages of using methods of class without instantiating

Tags: c++, instantiation

In c++ we can calls method of a class without instantiating it. Such as;

```
MyClass mc;
mc.method();
```

what are the advantages & disadvantages of using methods of class without instantiating it? When  should we use this type?

Comment: But you have instantiated it!

Comment: As it stands, this question makes no sense, because — as @sharjeel said — you _have_ instantiated the class. Voting to close as NARQ. (Feel free to flag for reopening when you fixed it.)

Comment: From the `[instantiation]` tag-wiki: "Instantiation is the process of creating an objects from a class in all object oriented and object based languages."

Comment: The OP may not understand a particular detail of how C++ works, but it doesn't follow that it isn't a real question.

Comment: Voting for reopening. OP misunderstood the C++ syntax, but it's a comprehensible mistake if he comes from a Java/C# background, and the question is definitely answerable (although with some tries).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You can still address the questioner (though it makes no sense, the important things have been said already), and the questioner can still reply, fix his question, and get it reopened. What's your problem?

Comment: @Xeo: Exactly the same code written in Java or C# will compile and fail at runtime, this isn't about the meaning of instantiation in general; it's about what this particular piece of code means in the context of C++.

Comment: @Marcelo: Ugh, with reference languages in mind, this question actually makes some sense now... We need a "read an effing book" close vote. Learning C++ without reading a good one is a trip to hell and back.

Comment: @Xeo i fixed that tag wiki re C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you haven't explicitly invoked a constructor, doesn't mean you haven't instantiated it. The form you've used invokes the default constructor. This may or may not setup the class correctly, but that's a matter for the class's author to sort out, not the code that uses it.

**EDIT:** It occurs to me that the advice I gave might confuse more than it helps, so I'll provide a couple of examples:

The following class has a trivial default constructor that doesn't initialise its members:

```
class Point {
    int x, y;
    Point() { }
    Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { }
};
```

You can use this class with or without an explicit constructor:

```
Point p;
Point r(2, 3);
```

In both forms above, the class is instantiated and the instance is ready for use without causing any crashes or invoking undefined behaviour. In the case of `p`, however, the member variables `x` and `y` haven't been initialised, and will thus have values that are, for all intents and purposes, random. Typically, you would populate such an object by setting its member variables explicitly...

```
Point a;
a.x = f();
a.y = g();
```

...or passing the object to another function to populate...

```
void f(Point& p) { p = something(); }
⋮
Point b;
h(b);
```

In other cases, the default constructor must initialise the object in a non-trivial way:

```
template <typename T>
class MyArray {
public:
    MyArray() : len_(0), capacity_(0), arr_(0) { }
    void add(const T& t) {
        if (len_ == capacity_) grow();
        arr_[len_++] = t;
    }
    ⋮
private:
    size_t len_, capacity_;
    T* arr_;

    void grow() { … }
};
```

The purpose of the constructor is to convert raw memory into a usable object. In the case of `Point`, no action is required for an instance to be usable. In the case of `MyArray`, `len_` and `capacity_` must be set to zero at construction time so that member functions like `add()` behave correctly (I also set `arr_` to the null pointer for good measure).

The key message in all of this is that the object may or may not be initialised, but it *is* instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing instantiating with whether you create it on the stack (in your example) or on the heap (with new).

Object lifetime (and memory management) aside, there's no real difference in calling the methods on one vs. the other.  It's more about object size and how long you need it to be around.